# Add heights of each matched element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have this function

```
            $('.gallery').each(function(){
                var thumbCount = $(this).find('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box').size();
                var rows = thumbCount/5;
                var height = rows*145;
                $(this).css({'height':height+24});
            });
```

Which gets the height of each `.gallery` div. I want to go one step further and take all of those `height` variables from inside the each function and add them together (getting the total height for all .gallery divs)-- but I don't know how.

Could someone show me the proper syntax for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your current code:

```
var totalHeight = 0;
$('.gallery').each(function(){
    var thumbCount = $(this).find('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box').size();
    var rows = thumbCount/5;
    var height = rows*145;
    totalHeight += height;
    $(this).css({'height':height+24});
});
```

---

BTW, here's how I might simplify your existing code a wee bit:

```
var totalHeight = 0;

$('.gallery').each(function(){
    var thumbCount = $(this).find('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box').length,
        rows = thumbCount/5,
        height = rows*145;

    totalHeight += height;

    $(this).css('height', height+24);
});
```